# Run a model multiple times with a for loop, rename it and append it to a list

Tags: r, list, for-loop, rename, renaming

I'm trying to run a model several times over a loop and then select the best one of them. For this I want to

1. change the name of each model with the line `assign(paste0("mod_match_logit", i), mod)` and
2. Then add each of the model into a list with the line `list.append(lis, eval(paste0("mod_match_logit", i)))`

---

```
library(MatchIt)
library(rlist)

lis = list()
for (i in 1:12){
  mod = matchit(f.build("var_1", df_cov), method = "nearest", distance = "logit", data = df_no_na, caliper = caliper_val, ratio = 2)
  assign(paste0("mod_match_logit", i), mod)
  list.append(lis, eval(paste0("mod_match_logit", i)))
  print(i)
}
lis
```

However there is no output from this command

Note: I could have run a logistic regression several times instead of a matching algorithm (i.e replacing the line `mod = matchit(f.build("var_1", df_cov), method = "nearest", distance = "logit", data = df_no_na, caliper = caliper_val, ratio = 2)` with `mod = glm(f.build("var_1", df_cov), data = df_no_na)`. But in the case of `glm`it is statistically not interesting as it will produce the same model each time whereas the model created with `Matchit` is a bit different each time.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out the foreach package.  It allows for greater control over the for loop output.  Along with that, you could store the model in a list using the rlang operator `:=` to do something like list(!! dynamic_name := model_output)

Comment: How does your  *mod* change with each iteration? They appear to return same results with each iteration? Is there some randomness occurring under the hood?

Comment: @Parfait: Indeed: as the return is each time a bit different, there is probably some randomness under the hood

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider `lapply`, similar to `for` as a loop, but returns a list object with equal length to its input here being `1:12`. No need to initialize an empty list and then fill in, use `assign` to save separate named objects, or attempt to reference objects dynamically with `eval(paste0(...))`:

```
lis <- lapply(1:12, function(i)
              matchit(f.build("var_1", df_cov), method = "nearest", distance = "logit", 
                      data = df_no_na, caliper = caliper_val, ratio = 2)
       )
```

Even add names accordingly:

```
names(lis) <- paste0("mod_match_logit", 1:12)

lis$mod_match_logit1
lis$mod_match_logit2
lis$mod_match_logit3
...
```